# Comparing Datetime SQL server and asp.net

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server, ado.net

I'm making a function that would cancel an order **only** if it's within **60 minutes**, what I was suggested is to compare the datetime value of the order to the current datetime.

```
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(Helper.GetCon()))
        {
            con.Open();
            string query = @"SELECT * from [Order] where orderid = @id";
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);
                using (SqlDataReader data = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                    dt.Load(data);
                    foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
                    {
                        var supplier = new Supplier();
                        supplier.OrderDate = DateTime.Parse(dr["OrderDate"].ToString());
                    }
                }
            }
            return View();
```

So far I've only taken the datetime from the database, I was wondering how you can get the current datetime and get the difference in let's say  **minutes** or **hours** so that I can make a conditional statement to allow or not allow the cancellation of an order. I'm fairly new to this and any help would be appreciated! 
Thank you!

Comment: Are you looking to filter this data in SQL Server, or your application (using C#)?

Comment: I'd much rather do it in my application for now

Comment: See msdn : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/date-and-time-data-types-and-functions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you must do it in the application rather than the SQL query, you can do something like:

```
var timeSinceOrder = DateTime.Now - supplier.OrderDate;

if(timeSinceOrder < TimeSpan.FromHours(1))
{
    //do stuff here
}
```

DateTime.Now gets the current time. Subtracting the order date from the current time returns a timespan that you can then compare to another timespan, in this case created by the function Timespan.FromHours.

Comment: Hey @Andrew! Thank you for the help. I tried the code and it worked flawlessly. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

Use DateDiff, comparing the selected date column with now and use the MINUTE difference:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(MINUTE, OrderDate , getdate()) AS MinuteDiff from [Order] where orderid =123
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use DateTime.Compare method.  Something like

```
If(DateTime.Compare(supplier.OrderDate, DateTime.Now) < 60)
{  
   //Enable Cancel/Delete Order
}
```